# Post from front end form to post_meta

Tags: php, posts, forms, front-end, post-meta

I want to save a value from the frontend of a post to the `post_meta` table.

Sofar I have this, but it won't save......
I have read that I could use the `update_post_meta` even if the `meta_key` doesn't exist.

```
<div>
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$meta_key = 'number';
$number1 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'number', TRUE);
?>
<form action="" method="post"  target="_self">
      <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="" />
      <p class="submit">
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Opslaan" />
      </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
if (isset ($_POST['number'])) {
    $number =  $_POST['number'];
} else {
    echo 'Empty';
}
$data = $_POST['number'];
    update_post_meta($postid,'number',$data);
}
```

This is a long way from being done but, can somebody point me in te right direction

Comment: had you tried this without checking `$data = $_POST['number'];
    update_post_meta($postid,'number',$data);` ?

Comment: How will the `update_post_meta` know what `$data` is then?

Comment: here `$data = $_POST['number'];`. You can try to just check if the submit button has been clicked.

Comment: I seriously have no idea what you mean :-)

Comment: replace your php code with this to see whether your check is correct or not:

`if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { $data = $_POST['number']; update_post_meta($postid,'number',$data); }`

Comment: Gives me nothing and my db stays empty

Comment: Got it. The problem was `if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post")` $_POST['action'] didn't exist. Thnx for you help !so far ;-)